# Clarification on the row_id returned by sqlite's insert statement

Tags: android, sqlite

Ok, we see [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues%29) that the `SQLite` insert statement returns something called `row id`.

When inserting, we know that `SQLite` likes a primary key column called ID and will auto-generate an appropriate value if the ID value being inserted is null.

The glue that's missing is confirmation that the `row id` returned by the `SQLiteDatabase.insert()` method is in fact the value that was auto-generated for the row's primary key. (This is not the case for Oracle...)

Will someone confirm or deny, please?

**Resolution**

Ok, so from the link posted by @sixfeetsix:

> Each entry in an SQLite table has a unique 64-bit signed integer key called the "rowid". The rowid is always available as an undeclared column... If the table has a column of type INTEGER PRIMARY KEY then that column is another alias for the rowid.

Then his `auto-increment` link verifies that the `row_id` and the auto-increment value will be the same value.

That's a wrap, thanks, folks!

Comment: What happened when you tried to see if the insert method returns the actual row id?

Comment: I haven't gotten that far.  I suspect the value returned is in fact going to be the auto-generated number.  However, If I insert the first row, and the value of '1' is returned, that doesn't mean that the value being returned is *always* the auto-generated number.  Now, if some other number was returned, I would know, of course.

Comment: I had the code all apart, took a while to make it compile.  Once I was able to run it, the value being returned is a plausible auto-generated value.  In short, I am not sure.  So I have a little more work to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Android insert(...) method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues%29) returns:

> the row ID of the newly inserted row, or -1 if an error occurred

This can be confusing to the uninitiated, but the [row id in sqlite](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/last_insert_rowid.html) is either the `integer primary key` field, or, in its absence, a 64-bit undeclared column named ROWID.

So when you insert either NULL or no value in an [auto-increment field](http://sqlite.org/autoinc.html), the generated value is returned.

Answer (score 2):

They are two separate things.

The row_id returned by `insert()` is the unique identifier for the row inserted, and it's an identifier used internally by SQLite.

On the other hand, you can have a column in the table that represents your business' key, declared:

```
_id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
```

So SQLite will generate values for that column for you.

As far as I see, there is no such function in SQLite like SQL Server's SCOPE_IDENTITY() (which returns the last autoincremental inserted id).

So, if you made an insert and need to retrieve the auto-generated id, you can do something like:

```
SELECT seq FROM sqlite_sequence WHERE name='tableName'
```

But take note that this is not a safe way in a concurrent scenario.

Comment: I must to correct myself. I think them as two different concepts, but like @sixfeetsix says, SQLite ties them together.